# I am getting syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING) in http://localhost:80/opt/lampp/htdocs/user_control.php

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying for user login and registration forms in Android. From past 5 days, I am trying it. I am not able to get it. Can anyone help me please? This is my code `user_control.php`. I am including the `connection.php` in `user_control.php`.

```
<? php

    class user {
    private $db;
    private $connection;
    /* The below one is the consttructor*/
    function __construct() {
        header('Content-Type: application/json'); /* used for including json format*/
        require_once 'connection.php';
        $this->db = new DB_Connection();
        $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
    }

    public function does_user_exist($email,$password) {
        $query = "Select * from userss where email ='$email' and password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $json['success'] = 'welcome'.$email;
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        } else {
            $query = " Insert into userss(email,password) values ('$email','$password')";
            $is_inserted = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
            if($is_inserted == 1) {
                $json['success'] = 'Account created, welcome '.$email;
            } else {
                $json['error'] = 'Wrong password';
            }

            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }
    }
}

    $user = new user();
    if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {
        $encrypted_password = md5($password);
        $user -> does_user_exist($email,$encrypted_password);
    } else {
        echo json_encode("You must fill both fields");

    }
    }
```

While I am running with postman software by Chrome I am getting the error as I am getting syntax error:

```
unexpected 'header' (T_STRING) in   http://localhost:80/opt/lampp/htdocs/user_control.php
```

Comment: `<? php` Remove the space between ? and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space in your line 1. Should looks like:

```
<?php
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to comment:

```
//header('Content-Type: application/json'); /* used for including json format*/
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620606/2381906

Comment: I did it. But now Iam getting 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dir/user_control.php on line 5

Comment: Remove the space between "<? php"
edit: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t_class

Comment: @NéstorLim If you have a *new* answer, the post a *new* answer.

Comment: Thanks @Biffen, don't want to flood.