# Azure functions: How does one access the contents of context.res.body?

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-functions

On my website, I use a fetch POST request on an azure function to store some data. If the function receives all the data, then `context.res.satus` is set to 200, and otherwise set to 400, and `context.res.body` is set to an acknowledgement message depending on how much of the data is received:

```
    var returnMessage = mail ? "User entry successfully added to the database" : "Please enter a valid email";
    returnMessage = phone ? returnMessage : "Please enter a valid phone number";
    returnMessage = lName ? returnMessage : "Please provide your last name";
    returnMessage = fName ? returnMessage : "Please procide your first name";
    returnMessage = partKey ? returnMessage : "Something went wrong while generating a partition key";

    context.res = {
        status: (partKey && fName && lName && phone && mail) ? 200 : 400,
        body: returnMessage
    };
```

So, I call `fetch('URL',someStuff).then((res) => processResponse(res))` in my code, and `res` is always returned absolutely fine and passed to `processResponse`, which looks like this:

```
function processResponse(response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        var test = JSON.stringify(response.body);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">${test}</div>`;
    }
}
```

If the function receives all the data, the div element 'output' is updated, and if it doesn't then it isn't, so the comparison of `response.status` to the value of 200 clearly works. the variable `test` I originally thought would work if set to `response.body`, but this didn't work, and instead the variable `test` would be set to the word 'Object'. I know very little about JSON but apparently we can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert Objects to Strings, hence why `test` is now `JSON.stringify(response.body)`, however this just makes the value of `test` equal to a set of empty square brackets. In the tutorial I am working from, they say to use `response.json()`, like so:

```
function processResponse(response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        response.json()
            .then(function(data) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">${data.message}</div>`;
            })
            .catch(function(){
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">"Caught"</div>`;
            });
    }
}
```

However every time I try `response.json()`, it fails and only the `.catch()` part runs. What is happening and how do I access the string stored in `response.body`?

Comment: Did my answer help, or running into the same/new problems?

Answer (score 1):

The function `response.json()` returns an error if the format is not json. You probably didn't set the `Content-Type: application/json` header in your post request! (see [HTTP Content-Type Header and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620300/http-content-type-header-and-json) for more info)